# heavy database operations cause freeze of UI in android

Tags: android

In my doinBackground() function of Asynctask I am inserting heavy data in my database. At the same time I want to scroll list on Activity. But when doinBackground execute, it freeze or hang my list. At that time I am not able to scroll the list.I struct on this fromlast 2 days. I have tried a lot for this, but didn't get any clear description and reason. So, plzz if there is any IDEA that how to resolve it, will be very appreciable. Thanks in advance.

int i =0;
for(int j = i; j

```
    for(int k = j; k<Integer.parseInt(listchscheduleArraylength.get(j));k++){

        if(databasehelper.insert_into_table2(list_ch_autoid.get(j), list_sch_prg_id.get(k), list_sch_prg_title.get(k)
                , list_sch_prg_gnre.get(k), list_sch_prg_sch_id.get(k), list_sch_prg_strt_time.get(k),
                list_sch_prg_end_time.get(k), list_sch_prg_sch_date.get(k), list_sch_prg_sch_desc.get(k))){

            Log.v("TABLE 2 status", "inserted");

        }else {
            Log.v("TABLE 2 status", " not inserted");
        }


    }// End of inner loop

    } // End of outer loop
```

Comment: add some code in the question

Comment: What you do in onPostExecute of asynctask

Comment: I have edited the question..plzz see it..before first forloop there are following two lines  int i =0;                                        for(int j = i; j<table1length; j++)

Comment: HI, Is Listview populated from database data ?

Comment: @HoodVinci..yes I am populated listeview from database...but if i do heavy insertion of record in database from backgroung then i freeze my UI

Comment: So the problem goes from here. Insertions are making a kind of lock on database acess. So it slows down reading from it. Are you displaying data being inserted ? You can try to improve performance on database accesses For instance try using a Loader if 's not yet the case. But if you are not displaying data which has just been inserted, just try seperating readings and writings. For instance load a big chunk of data to populate your listview and then  launch your asynctask.

Comment: @HoodVinci...thanks for that...